# Execute a rule one time for each fact

Tags: jess

How can I execute a rule for each fact only one time?

```
(defrule clean
     ?li<-(VISUAL::removedLine ?line)       
     ?cr<-(point (x ?px) (y ?py &: (< ?py ?line)))
     => 
     (modify ?cr (x ?px) (y (+ 1 ?py))))
```

When I execute this rule and make modify it will create a new point and execute the rule for that new point too.

For example:

```
 point (x 1) (y 2)
```

execute rule

```
 point (x 1) (y 3)
```

execute rule

```
 point (x 1) (y4)
```

I just want to make it execute one time, like this:

```
 point (x 1) (y 2)
```

execute rule

```
 point (x 1) (y 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Tetris player? :-)

Anyway, you have to use

```
(defrule clean
   (declare (no-loop TRUE)) 
   ?li<-(VISUAL::removedLine ?line)
```